# Display not working properly - monitor or graphics adapter?

Tags: adapter, display, dvi

I have a Dell ST2220L monitor connected to an Intel DH67CL's integrated graphics adapter using a DVI-I cable.

Everything was fine yesterday when I shut down the PC but today when I turned it on, I was presented with a screen that was completely white. This was present during pre-OS load and post-OS load.

I restarted the computer a few times and also switched the monitor on and off. After some time, the screen came back but it does not look OK. It's actually far from looking Ok. Following is a list of problems I can describe:

- The screen is too bright
- The colors aren't right
- The images and text don't seem right

Basically, it's broken in.

Now, what I am trying to figure out is, is this likely a problem with the monitor or the graphics adapter?

Before I can get this problem fixed, I want to figure out if it's a problem with the monitor or not. I already tried resetting the monitor settings

Comment: what were your last activities before shutting down? did you install something or removed or whatever?

Comment: Two things you might attempt to troubleshoot: 1) connect it to a different computer, and see if that works; 2) connect it with VGA or a different DVI cable, to rule out problems with that particular connector. If you have another monitor around, you might try a different monitor too to see if it's a problem with the monitor or not.

Comment: If you have a DVI adapter or VGA cable port can you test monitor?
Does monitor have a power on self test flash screen? Does it have a color edit screen?
Check connectors for bent or loose pins.